# jQuery function not working

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple jQuery function that is supposed to toggle a div's visibility:

```
jQuery( ".signUp" ).click(function() {
    $('.signUpForm').toggle();
});
```

The HTML is a simple signup form (hidden fields left out for brevity):

```
<p><a class="signUp" href="#">Sign Up!</a></p>
<div class="signUpForm">
    <h3 class="title">Join our email list!</h3>
        <form action="<url goes here>" method="POST">
        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="Email"/></br><br />
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" /><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

The script looks like it was enqueued properly, but it's not working on the WP page. It does work just fine on JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/danromanchik/6taton4p/).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you including the javascript?  Are you using [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) inside a callback [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Using_a_Hook)?

Comment: you're probably trying to bind the event handler before the markup exists in the DOM, your code should be wrapped in [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: After beating on it some more, I got it to work. The code in toggleForm.js is now: 

'jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery( ".signUp" ).click(function() {
  jQuery('.signUpForm').toggle();
 });
});'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery click event in a DOM ready function.

```
(function($) {
    $('.signUp').click(function() {
        $('.signUpForm').toggle();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your script though:

1. Using `wp_enqueue_script()` in themes `function.php`
   or
2. Use `wp_footer` action to add your `jQuery` script.

If your html in a shortcode then register your script using `wp_register_script('YOUR_HANDLE_NAME)`

and use `wp_enqueue_script('YOUR_HANDLE_NAME)`

Hope It helps...